# SQL query to return 2 values from different table

Tags: sql

I'm just learning SQL and cannot do one thing.

I have 2 tables:

Persons:

```
CREATE TABLE Persons 
(
    `id` INT,
    `name` TEXT,
    `id_region1` INT,
    `id_region2` INT,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);

INSERT INTO Persons VALUES (1, 'pp1', 1, 1);
INSERT INTO Persons VALUES (2, 'pp2', 2, 1);
INSERT INTO Persons VALUES (3, 'pp3', 2, 3);
```

Region

```
CREATE TABLE Region 
(
    `id_region` INT,
    `region_name` TEXT,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id_region`)
);

INSERT INTO Region VALUES (1, 'AAA');
INSERT INTO Region VALUES (2, 'BBB');
INSERT INTO Region VALUES (3, 'CCC');
```

I would like to get this result:

```
1 | pp1 | AAA | AAA 
2 | pp2 | BBB | AAA 
3 | pp3 | BBB | CCC
```

I tried to use a join, but it cannot be done to same column.

Comment: LEFT JOIN regions twice. (One time per person region.)

Comment: ok but how to display that in columns?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`LEFT JOIN` region table twice. (One time per person region.)

```
select p.id, p.name. r1.region_name, r2.region_name
from persons p
left join region r1 on p.id_region1 = r1.id_region
left join region r2 on p.id_region2 = r2.id_region
```

(Do LEFT JOIN just in case, if a person has 0 or 1 region only.)